# Rules replacement pattern missing

Tags: rules

I have a content type including these two fields

[image: content type fields]

and now I want to use those fields in a "Rules" action, but they are not present in the replacement patterns to choose, and they're not present in the Data Selection  mode either.

What have I missed? Would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

My rule export code

```
{ "rules_fiberbest_llningsemail" : {
"LABEL" : "Fiberbest\u00e4llningsemail",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
"ON" : { "node_insert--fiberbestallning" : { "bundle" : "fiberbestallning" } },
"IF" : [
  { "node_is_of_type" : {
      "node" : [ "node" ],
      "type" : { "value" : { "fiberbestallning" : "fiberbestallning" } }
    }
  }
],
"DO" : [
  { "mail" : {
      "to" : "me@example.com",
      "subject" : "Fiberbest\u00e4llning",
      "message" : "Ny fiberbest\u00e4llning fr\u00e5n hemsidan skapad [node:created]\r\n\r\n[node:url]\r\n[node:field-f-rnamn]\r\n[node:field-efternamn]\r\n[node:field-adresss]\r\n[node:field-postnummer]\r\n[node:field-postadress]\r\n[node:field-fibertyp]",
      "language" : [ "" ]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

Add Condition >> Content is of Type >> [your content type]

OR

Add Condition >> Entity Has Field >> node:field-telefon

Add Condition >> Entity Has Field >> node:field-signatur

OR

Add Action >> Fetch Entity by Property >> Node >> telefon >> node:field-telefon

Add Action >> Fetch Entity by Property >> Node >> signatur >> node:field-signatur

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your reply

I tried this, but none of the these adds the fields in the replacement pattern. I can see them just fine in the "Entity Has Field" condition, but they are still not present in the Action.

Comment: @duzzy that is very odd, can you post the export code of your rule?

Comment: edited original post

Comment: @duzzy hmmm, not even Add Action >> Fetch Entity by Property worked?

Comment: @duzzy what module are you using to add the phone number field?

Comment: Im using cck_phone, however I am concidering to remove it and just use a normal text field. Not worth the trouble to get this working. Thanks though @no-sssweat for your input, appreciate it.

Comment: @dizzy, I installed it and works for me `[node:field-telefon]` appears as a replacement patter for e-mail body.

Comment: @duzzy see my [example here](https://d0c23.ply.st)

Comment: My 2 cents (based on my own experience): "entity has field" (for the field you'r interested in) is always the best bet ... To the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module it's like saying "hey, I want to do something with that field, please make it available" ... Extra guess: since event in rule here was "after insert of node of type 'fiberbestallning', I bet the Rules condition "if content type is fiberbestallning" is possibly just ignored ... and hence its custom fields are not made available ... Would be interesting to see what happened if event is just without test on type ...